# CSP Report in console: How to turn off through .net code, the csp report logged in browser console

Tags: .net-core, console, content-security-policy

I have the CSP report only enabled for my .net project. I see the CSP report being written to the URI I mentioned, but at the same time, [report only] messages logged in my browser console. I don't want my browser to be clogged with these messages as I am getting the reports where I wanted them to be in the report-uri. Is there a way to disable or turn off the CSP report logging in the console, through the code or web config in .netcore

Answer (score 0):

The `SecurityPolicyViolationEvent` is [not cancelable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelable). Even you catch it and handle, the `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` methods have no effect on it.

Furthermore some CSP errors appears in the browser console only and not in violation reports. So it can be dangerous to switch off errors console logging.

Comment: granty, do you happen to remember why some errors would appear in the browser console only?